# Ruby: Can't convert String to Symbol after scan with regexp

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

After running regexp on my string, I return all the mathes with scan (which returns an array of strings). I try to convert every element to_sym but it doesn't work properly.

My code looks like this:

```
path = "tests/:id/question/:title"

res = path.scan(/:\w+/)

res.map!(&:to_sym)
```

eventually I get:

```
=> [:":id", :":title"]
```

instead of `[:id, :title]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because with /:\w+/ you're also getting the ":" as a part of the string.

Try without taking the ":", and then you're able to convert those strings to symbols:

```
'tests/:id/question/:title'.scan(/(?<=:)\w+/).map(&:to_sym)
# [:id, :title]
```